# I can’t install the libp11 library on Windows

Tags: windows, github, installation, pkcs#11

I followed the installation of the library on the github:

"https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11/blob/master/INSTALL.md" by testing with many methods (CYGWIN,MINGW).

But every time I try to install it I have different errors. Did someone have a method that would allow to install it correctly because for now for each method I have errors .